# expectation with indicator functions

Tags: probability

I came across this inequality and I could not understand how they found it:

$$
(E[X \mathbb{1_{X>0}}])^2 < E[X^2]P(X>0)
$$

Can you explain the necessary steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory).
$$(E[X \mathbb{1_{X>0}}])^{2} \leq  E[X^{2}]\, E[\mathbb{1^2_{X>0}}]=E[X^{2}]\, E[\mathbb{1_{X>0}}]=E[X^{2}]\,P(X>0).$$